# Want to add delete functions for a list of date displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery

to summarize my problem ... I have made a calendar with contains the from - to date range. Now the selected dates are displayed in a div with a delete button for each. But as the id of the button is the same for all the dates ....it deletes the entire date range. I have attached the screenshot as well.

[image]

I also tried taking a loop and giving each date a div so that the Del function will work properly. but I wasn't successful. I will mention code for the same

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i = 0;
    $.each(between, function (key, value) {
        var rest = $('#target').append($('<div id="r' + i +value+ '" class="ansbox"> 
        </div>'));
        console.log(between);

        var template = '<div id="ChildTarget_' + i + '"><span>key + ":" + "' + value + '" 
        </span><button id="tr' + i + '" class="target">X</button></div><br></div>';

        i++;
        $('#target').on('click', function () {
        console.log("hola");
        $('#target').remove();
```

Comment: `But as the id of the button is same for all the dates ...` IDs must be unique. You shouldn't be repeating them. Use classname instead

Answer (score 0):

You should add click event for the button itself.

```
 var template = `
<div id="ChildTarget_' + i + '">
    <span>key + ":" + "' + value + '"</span>
    <button id="tr' + i + '" class="deleteButton">X</button>
</div>`;
$(".deleteButton').on('click', function() {
   // do deletion here
});
```

Comment: Okay ! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all , 
The 'X' button should have different id

```
$.each(between, function (key, value){
      $('#results').append(key+":"+value+'<br>');
      $('#results').html(between.join('<button id="result"+key+"" > X </button><br>')
```

here you can see i am adding key to the Button Id making it unique. Use that id to remove the value, that you dont want. Hope this helps

Comment: Okay i will try this.Thank you!

Comment: @Punam did u get any result